# Por que deveria usar File::copy, se no PHP já existe copy?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, classes, funções

Eu estou utilizando o `Laravel` em vários projetos que uso.

Precisei de copiar um determinado arquivo de um local para outro, e vi na documentação do Laravel que deveria utilizar [`File::copy()`](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_copy).

Por curiosidade, como sempre faço, resolvi dar uma olhada no código-fonte, pra saber como esse método foi construído e me surpreendi.

A classe File é um facade para `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`, que é a "classe real".

Vejam o código-fonte do método `File::copy()`

```
     /**
     * Copy a file to a new location.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $target
     * @return bool
     */
    public function copy($path, $target)
    {
        return copy($path, $target);
    }
```

Isso faz parecer que `File::copy` é um facade para a função nativa `copy`.

Sendo assim, quais são os motivos de utilizar o método copy, já que ele é simplesmente um retorno da função `copy` do PHP?

Devo utilizar `File::copy` apenas apenas para manter o padrão de codificação do framework?

Comment: Realmente parece redundante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ideia dos frameworks é criar uma camada de alto nível para facilitar o uso de alguns recursos da linguagem, separando o seu código de uma implementação específica resultando assim em um baixo acoplamento da sua lógica à implementação, favorecendo o reuso.

Nesse caso específico a implementação está executando uma função nativa, porém podemos substituir essa classe por uma outra implementação sem alterar o seu código original.

Um ótimo exemplo é a classe `Filesystem` do próprio Laravel, que na versão [5.0 foi substituída por um componente externo](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem) que agora suporta, além de arquivos locais, arquivos em provedores na nuvem, como Amazon S3. Isso tudo sem precisarmos alterar uma linha do código da nossa aplicação.

Comment: Ah, aí você notou em um ponto positivo que eu tinha imaginado :). Porque se, dentro da classe, eles usam `$this->copy`, quando precisar alterar esse método, todas as alterações serão aplicadas... reutilização :>

Comment: também há o fato de funções nativas entrarem em desuso ou mesmo trocar de nome..