# É ruim usar o mecanismo padrão de sessão do PHP?

Tags: php, session

Percebo é que muitos *frameworks*, como Codeigniter e Laravel 3 e 4 utilizam um mecanismo próprio de armazenamento de sessão. Eles não usam o mecanismo padrão do PHP (Variável `$_SESSION` e `session_start`, entre outras coisas).

E quando digo "mecanismo próprio" eu não estou falando de mudar o comportamento da sessão do PHP com a interface `SessionHandler` ou `session_set_save_handler`, mas estou falando de trabalhar com um mecanismo para criação da sessão, sem utilizar nenhum dos recursos (já prontos) do PHP.

Gostaria de saber se há algo ruim com o mecanismo padrão de sessão do PHP?

Existe alguma limitação na sessão nativa do PHP, para que os *frameworks* utilizem outra maneira de implementar sessões?

Comment: Acho que as pessoas reclamam mais da sessão do CI do a do PHP :D.

Comment: Não consigo afirmar categoricamente. Acho que não há problema se souber usar. Acredito que *frameworks* usem de um jeito mais fácil de fazer certo e seja uma camada de abstração que permita modificar no futuro a implementação concreta, além de dar algumas flexibilidades e características adicionais. Que tem limitação, tem, tudo tem. Tudo está limitado ao que aquilo faz. Se precisa de mais, é outra questão.

Comment: É claro, o pessoal do CI dão duas opções: Database e Cookie. Usar cookie como sessão é uma opção muito meia boca. Aí é melhor dar um session_start no meio de um código que não deveria usá-lo

Comment: @bigown interessante. Você respondeu algo parecido com o gmsantos nessa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73058/por-que-deveria-usar-filecopy-se-no-php-j%C3%A1-existe-copy

Comment: Aparentemente gera race conditions no caso do lavarel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5416#issuecomment-68366445. Lembro de já ter enfrentando problemas similares com native session de php na in-house framework que mantenho no trabalho, mas faz algum tempo e não lembro exatamente o que era e como resolvemos, só que foi chato pra burro.

Comment: Não é ruim utilizar a sessão do PHP, o que torna ruim é a forma como alguns programadores à utilizam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como todo recurso é preciso entendê-lo completamente, ler toda documentação e eventualmente procurar informações não documentadas. Algo complexo como este pode ter uma série de detalhes que podem passar desapercebidos. Não vou tentar colocar tudo o que precisa ser verificado, até porque não sou especialista no assunto, e acho que nem cabe, minha intenção não é dar uma resposta definitiva.

O motivo principal de *frameworks* prover mecanismos próprios para qualquer tecnologia é a abstração do recurso.

[**Abstração**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23103/101) é um dos conceitos mais mal entendidos da computação. Ela sempre existiu antes mesmo de existirem os computadores modernos. A abstração dá mais significado ao que se está fazendo e coloca uma camada em cima do concreto, permitindo que a implementação real seja escondida do usuário daquele recurso.

Uma das maiores vantagens da abstração é que se ela for bem feita pode trocar a implementação sem exigir que os códigos que a usam sejam modificados. Isso é muito importante em diversos cenários. Nem sempre é possível fazer bem feito, por melhor que seja o programador. E nem sempre a complicação da abstração que será necessária vale o esforço.

Então é interessante que estes produtos tenham uma forma que pelo menos não dependa do padrão do PHP.

E como o padrão tem uma implementação relativamente simples e fixa é natural que eles forneçam uma implementação mais poderosa e flexível. Consigo imaginar um monte de coisas que sejam possíveis fazer em uma sessão além do que a implementação padrão fornece. Há vários cenários onde a padrão não atende bem. Embora a maioria dos cenários dispensa qualquer outra solução.

Além de obviamente suprir mais informações, uma melhor integração com banco de dados e distribuição de sessão e transporte e informação de identificação de outra forma e contagem de sessões ativas são alguns exemplos do que pode ser melhorado.

Como foi dito em comentários, o fato de criar uma versão própria, não quer dizer que ficará melhor. Ainda que a intenção desses *frameworks* seja facilitar o uso dos recursos em relação ao que existe no PHP. Talvez a tentativa de fazer algo melhor tenha deixado complexo demais.

A maioria dos problemas que eu vejo com o uso da sessão padrão tem a ver com o uso errado. Ok, pode ser um pouco difícil fazer certo, mas é obrigação do programador saber fazer isto. E os *frameworks* terão que escolher entre facilitar ou dar um recurso mais poderoso e flexível. O que eu vejo eles fazerem muito é aplicar as tais das boas práticas, ou seja, eles escolhem o que é bom para você, mesmo que aquilo não seja o melhor sempre.

Pelo tamanho da [página da documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) de apenas uma função dá para ter uma ideia de como é complicado usar direito, de forma segura, mas não tem muito o que fazer quando o problema é complexo (ainda que seja um exagero chamá-lo de complexo).

> Gostaria de saber se há algo ruim com o mecanismo padrão de sessão do PHP?

Se fosse tão problemático já teria bastante recomendação para não usar, alguém já teria feito um substituto no PHP. É bom ter uma informação aqui, mas o problema não está no recurso, está na pecinha entre o teclado e a cadeira :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ótima resposta, como sempre. +1

Answer (score 6):

Depende. O uso de *sessions* padrão do PHP não apresenta problemas de forma geral, contudo ele *pode ser ruim* dependendo de como é utilizado. O [*save handler* padrão](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) usa arquivos, assim em cada *request* recebido, mesmo com você não usando a sessão em alguns, vai rolar um *lock* nos arquivos de sessão e uma subsequente leitura deles, isso pode representar um *overhead* relevante se você tiver uma quantidade realmente grande de *requests*.

Outro detalhe é que, como eu já disse, fazer um *request* gera um *lock* no seu arquivo de sessão (cujo caminho padrão é algo como `/var/lib/php/session/sess_$identifier`), sendo assim quaisquer *requests* concorrentes tem que esperar a liberação desse *lock* para que possam proceder. O *lock* inicia em `session_start()` e termina no fim da execução do seu *script*, ou na chamada de `session_write_close()`, dessa maneira caso você tenha uma situação em que o cliente faça vários AJAX *requests* seguidos para o servidor todos esses *requests* entram em fila esperando o que chegou antes liberar o lock do arquivo de sessão, e isso é realmente ruim. O ideal para minimizar esse problema é sempre usar `session_write_close()` o mais próximo possível do início da sessão, caso contrário *requests* concorrentes vão ter que esperar o fim da execução do *script* que chegou primeiro, o que pode significar uma pancada de operação (ler arquivos, acessar *database*, processar coisas, etc).

Um outro problema que parece levar várias *frameworks* a evitarem o uso das *sessions* padrão de PHP é o fato de que `session_start()`, assim que invocado, sempre envia o *cookie* de sessão para o cliente. O problema aqui é relacionado com o descrito no parágrafo anterior, você quer fechar a sessão o mais rápido possível após abrir ela, contudo talvez você queira fazer algo como escrever algo na sessão no fim do seu PHP *script* e caso já tenha fechado ela vai precisar reabrir. Nessa situação você tem o problema de que provavelmente vai receber um erro similar a `Headers already sent` pois em HTTP o cabeçalho é sempre enviados antes do conteúdo, e num estágio tardio do seu *script* é provável que você já tenha terminado de enviar o cabeçalho e começado a mandar conteúdo e a chamada de `session_start()` vai tentar enviar mais cabeçalho (o *cookie*).

Por fim nós temos a questão já comentada na resposta do Maniero, que embora tão abstrata que de para você usar ela em 90% das perguntas conceituais de programação (hah é zoeira em, a resposta é boa ;) ), explica bem o fato de que você muitas vezes quer um controle maior que aquele dado por uma implementação nativa, ou quer ter uma acesso a uma abstração diferente, ou quer algo mais flexível, ou ainda quer uma implementação cuja funcionamento seja mais fácil de compreender (que saber o que rola por baixo dos panos, sem "mágica").

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38104

Comment: no finzinho tem a nota do conserto: demorou hein, arrumaram nao faz nem um ano. :D  _[2015-08-11 10:36 UTC] yohgaki@php.net Time goes by. 
I fixed this already. If you have problem, please open new bug report._